# Center a label in the south container of a border layout in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

In my Codename One app, while the app is sending a query, I want to show an `InfiniteProgress` in the center and below it a centered Label which tells the user what is going on. So I created a container with `BorderLayout` and added the infinite progress with constraint `BorderLayout.CENTER` and a container with `BorderLayout.SOUTH` constraint, which contains the label. The inner container layout is `BorderLayout` with `BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER_ABSOLUTE`. I then just add the label with constraint `BorderLayout.CENTER`, and this does center the label. However, when I try to change the text of the label to something longer, it gets cut. The problem can be demonstrated using the below simple example:

```
    Form hi = new Form("Welcome", new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER_ABSOLUTE));
    Button button = new Button("Change text");
    Label label = new Label("South");
    button.addActionListener(event -> {
        label.setText("A lot longer text");
    });
    hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, button);

    Container container = new Container();
    container.setLayout(new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER_ABSOLUTE));
    container.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, label);
    hi.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, container);
    hi.show();
```

Now, when I click on the button to change the text of the label, you can see that the label does not show the whole text (see pictures).

[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line after you set the label text:

```
label.getParent().revalidate();
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought that Label will set this automatically as it does in a lot of cases, but I sure should have tried this one.

Comment: repaint() is invoked, revalidate() is much slower as it needs to reflow the UI so it isn't implicit. That also allows things like `animateLayout()` which wouldn't work if revalidate was implicit

Comment: So, the difference between repaint() and revalidate() is that revalidates() puts all components again in the container, so for example I would call revalidate() when adding a component to a container, and repaint() just repaints the component, and I would call it when I change the appearance of the component, like in this example. Did I understood correctly the difference between the two?

Comment: repaint draws but doesn't re-arrange boundaries. Revalidate reflows the UI which means it can shift component boundaries. This is discussed in the developer guide where we cover the value of animateLayout() which is a form of revalidate that performs that action as an animation...